# People who share the same native language are language mates?

Tags: word-request

Can I call a person who speaks the same language as mine, a language mate? Considering that's our mother tongue and we're from different countries. For example, I'm Brazilian and the other person is Portuguese and we both speak Portuguese.

Comment: What do you mean by "can I"? Are you asking whether you would be understood? Whether that's a common collocation used by native speakers?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes I wanted to know if this a common collocation, and if it's not, how can I create this sense of unity between me and the other person. You see I saw a post on Instagram in which those people who speak my language were celebrating a holiday. I kind of wanted to make this bond with them by saying something like, "Happy holidays to all my language mates!" Then i thought how I could say it in English. Is there a word for that in English?

Comment: And I'm American and have lots of English friends: fellow English speakers. A language mate as opposed to what football mates? mates does not really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a common word for this in English. Your invented term of "language mates" will probably be understood, so feel free to use it.

You could also say something like:

> Happy holidays to all my **fellow speakers of Portuguese**.